# Query to obtain start and end dates from table with only start dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with dates and values, something like:

```
START_DATE    VALUE
------------  -----
01-JAN-2015     A
01-MAR-2015     B
01-AUG-2015     (null)
15-AUG-2015     A
01-SEP-2015     C
01-JAN-2016     B
01-JUN-2016     C
```

Each start_date represents the date when the value changed.
I'm trying to obtain an output that includes the end date as the next date (in chronological order) minus one day, that is:

```
START_DATE    END_DATE    VALUE
----------    ----------  -----
01-JAN-2015   28-FEB-2015   A
01-MAR-2015   31-JUL-2015   B
01-AUG-2015   14-AUG-2015   (null)
15-AUG-2015   31-AUG-2015   A
01-SEP-2015   31-DEC-2015   C
01-JAN-2016   31-MAY-2016   B
01-JUN-2016   (null)        C
```

Is there a query I can use to obtain the start and end date for each interval?... maybe using hierarchical queries?

Here, an excerpt I'm using during development that can save some time:

```
with my_table 
          as(
          select to_date('01-JAN-2015') start_date,'A' value from dual
          union
          select to_date('01-MAR-2015') start_date,'B' value from dual
          union
          select to_date('01-AUG-2015') start_date,'' value from dual
          union
          select to_date('15-AUG-2015') start_date,'A' value from dual
          union
          select to_date('01-SEP-2015') start_date,'C' value from dual
          union
          select to_date('01-JAN-2016') start_date,'B' value from dual
          union
          select to_date('01-JUN-2016') start_date,'C' value from dual
          )
          select ...
```

Comment: How did you get 30-APR as end_date for the first row? When the next row has start_date of 01-MAR?

Comment: Thanks @mathguy... the correct end date should be 28_FEB-2015. Post corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select start_date, lead(start_date) over (order by start_date) - 1 as end_date, value
from   my_table
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

WITH A AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN , A.* FROM SALESNEW A)

SELECT X.START_DATE, Y.START_DATE-1 AS END_DATE, X.VALUE FROM A X , A Y
WHERE (CASE WHEN X.RN>=1 THEN X.RN+1 END) = Y.RN(+);

Comment: You should check `row_num()` syntaxis

Comment: Sorry here is the modified query
WITH A AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN , A.* FROM SALESNEW A)

SELECT X.START_DATE, Y.START_DATE-1 AS END_DATE, X.VALUE FROM A X , A Y
WHERE (CASE WHEN X.RN>=1 THEN X.RN+1 END) = Y.RN(+)

Comment: i am using oracle and i ran it in my SQL developer , its working fine